# How to reflect the function output under addRows in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a php file with an array output and I want to send it to a javascript file. I created a function with `$get()` but I don't know how to reflect under `data.addRows`. I debugged it with `console.log(data2)` and I saw the array, but don't know how to reflect the output under `addRows`.

data.php:

```
<?php 
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo " 
          ['".$row['time']."',".$row['temp'].",".$row['hum']."],";
        }
    }
?>
```

script.js:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

function drawLineColors() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');

    $.get('data.php').then(function(data2){ 

     ///I made here console.log(data2) and I got the array like this 
 ['2019-05-13 00:25:13',27.20,41.00],['2019-05-13 00:26:00',27.20,41.00],

        data.addRows([//I want to know how to reflected here!]);

     let rowIndex = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1;
     let lastTime = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0); 
     let lastTemp = data.getValue(rowIndex, 1); 
     let lastHum = data.getValue(rowIndex,2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't build your array with strings concatenation but with JSON.

Use [json-encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $data[] = array($row['time'], $row['temp'], $row['hum']); 
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in the JS file you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as:

```
obj = JSON.parse(data2);
data.addRows(obj);
```

Comment: thanks for helping me I used `json-encode` in `data.php` now how can I show the array under `data.addRows` ?

Comment: @M.Saeed use JSON.parse - update my answer. console.log the data2 to verify this is in the right format

Comment: thanks for helping me but the array output in `$data[]` are string how can I make them to be as a number?

Comment: yes i got it with add `(int)` before `$row` but the number is `24` but the real is `24.5` can make it as real? thanks again for helping me

Comment: `floatval` (PHP) is maybe the one you need